# All indices of each unique element in a list python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas, indexing

I'm working with a very large data set (about 75 million entries) and I'm trying to shorten the length of time that running my code takes by a significant margin (with a loop right now it will take a couple days) and keep memory usage extremely low.

I have two numpy arrays (`clients` and `units`) of the same length. My goal is to get a list of every index that a value occurs in my first list (`clients`) and then find a sum of the entries in my second list at each of those indices.

This is what I've tried (`np` is the previously imported numpy library)

```
# create a list of each value that appears in clients
unq = np.unique(clients)
arr = np.zeros(len(unq))
tmp = np.arange(len(clients))
# for each unique value i in clients
for i in range(len(unq)) :
    #create a list inds of all the indices that i occurs in clients
    inds = tmp[clients==unq[i]]
    # add the sum of all the elements in units at the indices inds to a list
    arr[i] = sum(units[inds])
```

Does anyone know a method that will allow me to find these sums without looping through each element in `unq`?

Comment: Would pandas be an option for you?

Comment: Pandas are always an option.

Comment: I'm using pandas to upload and download the arrays, is there another way I could use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), this can easily be done using the [`grouby()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) function:

```
import pandas as pd

# some fake data
df = pd.DataFrame({'clients': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'a'], 'units': [1, 1, 1, 1]})

print df.groupby(['clients'], sort=False).sum()
```

which gives you the desired output:

```
         units
clients       
a            3
b            1
```

I use the `sort=False` option since that might lead to a speed-up (by default the entries will be sorted which can take some time for huge datsets).

Comment: Thank you so much! This is great!

Comment: @downvoter: Could you please explain your downvote? Is it because it is a numpy and not a pandas question? Then you might check the comments below the question where I asked about whether pandas would be an option... If anything else is wrong with it, please point it out!

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical group-by type operation, which can be performed elegantly and efficiently using the [numpy-indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (disclaimer: I am its author):

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
unique_clients, units_per_client = npi.group_by(clients).sum(units)
```

Note that unlike the pandas approach, there is no need to create a temporary datastructure just to perform this kind of elementary operation.

Comment: Interesting. Have never heard about this package. Any ideas how it scales to the pandas solution I added above? Apparently, someone does not really like it but prefers your solution so I wonder whether yours is indeed far more efficient... :)

Comment: I would imagine that they are similar in terms of performance. However, pandas is a heavy dependency, conceptually speaking, for such an elementary operation. As someone reading the pandas solution, I might wonder what a dataframe is, and what it has to do with grouping; and the answer is essentially 'nothing whatsoever'.